# Azure app service with unsecure custom domain and front door

Tags: azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate, azure-front-door

I have an app service with front door setup on Azure and have added a custom domain to the front door.

To ensure the request url is recorded correctly on server, I have cleared the "Backend host header" property on the defaultPool on the front door.

This initially resulted in a 404 when using my custom domain, but adding the same domain to the app service fixed that issue.

Since I don't want to use my own certificates, the front door is using one generated by azure, and the custom domain on the app service does not have a certificate, resulting in the Custom domains page showing a warning.

Is this the correct way to setup an App service with a front door and a custom domain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which *backend host header* you removed from the default pool, but I'm thinking that wasn't necessary. After [adding your custom domain to AFD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-add-custom-domain) you can use an [Azure managed certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-configure-https-custom-domain#azure-managed-certificates). I would simply go that route. But if you have any issues, comment down below.